# How can I declare get accessors and/or set accessors to retrieve lists?

Tags: c#, list, getter-setter, code-cleanup

In my class, I have a method that loops through all network interfaces and adds values to three different lists. I then take those three individual lists and I add them to one combined list so that I can work on them in a different solution.

This is where I get lost. I want to use the get accessor to retrieve the lists from the `GetAllNetworkInfo` method per network interface, meaning for each network interface I want to get the three lists. I would think that this should be a simple answer but I have not used get/set before and my mind is drawing a blank.

Can this be done? If so, how?

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class NetworkInformation
{
    private static List<string> _listOfIPs = new List<string>();
    private static List<string> _listOfSubnets = new List<string>();
    private static List<string> _listOfGateways = new List<string>();
    private static List<List<string>> _myList = new List<List<string>>();

    public static object GetAllNetworkInfo()
    {
        NetworkInterface[] networkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
        foreach (NetworkInterface networkInterface in networkInterfaces)
        {
            IPInterfaceProperties adapterProperties = networkInterface.GetIPProperties();
            GatewayIPAddressInformationCollection addresses = adapterProperties.GatewayAddresses;
            if (networkInterface.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
            {
                UnicastIPAddressInformationCollection unicastIPC = networkInterface.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses;
                foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation unicast in unicastIPC)
                {
                    if (unicast.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                    {
                        _listOfIPs.Add(unicast.Address.ToString());
                        _listOfSubnets.Add(unicast.IPv4Mask.ToString());
                    }

                    if (addresses.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (GatewayIPAddressInformation address in addresses)
                        {
                            _listOfGateways.Add(address.Address.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
                _dict.Add(iP, subnet);
                _myList.Add(_listOfIPs);
                _myList.Add(_listOfGateways);
                _myList.Add(_listOfSubnets);
        }

        return _myList;
    }

    //this is my blind attempt to get the values. Not sure if this will even work
    public static List<string> IPAddressList
    {
        get
        {
            return _listOfIPs;
        }
    }

    public static List<string> SubnetList
    {
        get
        {
            return _listOfSubnets;
        }
    }

    public static List<string> GatewayList
    {
        get
        {
            return _listOfGateways;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try this code to see if it works? The main downside I see is that the user must call `GetAllNetorkInfo` at least once before using the three properties. Instead, the property could check to see if it was `null` or an empty list (but probably `null` in case it is possible to have an empty list?) and if so call the function.

Comment: The code itself compiles and I do get the values, but there is no way of knowing what value belongs to what interface. I guess that is the main problem. @crashmstr

Comment: @DesmondLost It is unclear how you plan to use this code "per network interface". Would you want to pass in a network interface name and then receive all the lists for that interface? Or would you like to get back a List for all interfaces but that is grouped by each individual interface?

Comment: In a separate solution, I will be iterating through a server list and foreach server, I would like to get back a list of all interfaces and its corresponding IPs, subnets, and gateways. @JesseCarter

Comment: @DesmondLost Please check out the answer I posted, it should be able to help you accomplish what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking to do something like this:

```
public class NetworkInformation
{
private static Dictionary<string, List<string>> _listOfIPs = null;
private static Dictionary<string, List<string>> _listOfSubnets = null;
private static Dictionary<string, List<string>> _listOfGateways = null;
private static List<Dictionary<string, List<string>>> _myList = new List<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>();

public static object GetAllNetworkInfo()
{
    if ( _listOfIPs == null || _listOfSubnets == null || _listofGateways == null ) {
        _listOfIPs = new Dictionary<string, List<string>();
        _listOfSubnets = new Dictionary<string, List<string>();
        _listOfGateways = new Dictionary<string, List<string>();
     } else {
         _listOfIPs.Clear();
         _listOfSubnets.Clear();
         _listOfGateways.Clear();
     }
     _myList.Clear();

    NetworkInterface[] networkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
    foreach (NetworkInterface networkInterface in networkInterfaces)
    {
        _listOfIPs.Add( networkInterface.Name, new List<string>);
        _listOfSubnets.Add( networkInterface.Name, new List<string>);
        _listOfGateways.Add( neworkdInterface.Name, new List<string>);

        IPInterfaceProperties adapterProperties = networkInterface.GetIPProperties();
        GatewayIPAddressInformationCollection addresses = adapterProperties.GatewayAddresses;
        if (networkInterface.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
        {
            UnicastIPAddressInformationCollection unicastIPC = networkInterface.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses;
            foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation unicast in unicastIPC)
            {
                if (unicast.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    _listOfIPs[ networkInterface.Name ].Add(unicast.Address.ToString());
                    _listOfSubnets[ networkInterface.Name].Add(unicast.IPv4Mask.ToString());
                }

                if (addresses.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (GatewayIPAddressInformation address in addresses)
                    {
                        _listOfGateways[ networkInterface.Name ].Add( address.Address.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
            _dict.Add(iP, subnet);
            _myList.Add(_listOfIPs);
            _myList.Add(_listOfGateways);
            _myList.Add(_listOfSubnets);
    }

    return _myList;
}

public static Dictionary<string,string> IPAddressList
{
    get
    {
        if ( _listOfIPs == null || _listofSubnets == null || _listOfGateways == null )
            GetAllNetworkInfo()
        return _listOfIPs;
    }
}

public static Dictionary<string,string> SubnetList
{
    get
    {
        if ( _listOfIPs == null || _listOfSubnets == null || _listOfGateways == null )
            GetAllNetworkInfo()
        return _listOfSubnets;
    }
}

public static Dictionary<string,string> GatewayList
{
    get
    {
        if ( _listOfIPs == null || _listofSubnets == null || _listOfGateways == null )
            GetAllNetworkInfo()
        return _listOfGateways;
    }
}
```

I switched the `Lists` to `Dictionaries` so the `NetworkInterface` information wouldn't be lost.  Frankly, I'm not sure that's what you're after, but it does preserve the information.  Now you can query the `Dictionary` by `NetWorkInterface` name.

This time I changed the `Dictionaries` into `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`, which will  hold more than one IP per Network Interface, for example.

Comment: This will not return the list per network interface as per the OP's request

Comment: I missed that.  I changed the `Lists` into `Dictionaries` that use the `NetworkInterface` name as the key.

Comment: The use of dictionaries here is not correct. You're very quickly going to run into a key already present exception if there is more than even one IP address per network interface.

Comment: Yep, you're right.  Changed the answer again.  Changed the Dictionaries into Dictionary<string, List<string>>, which will handle multiple items per network interface.

Comment: Hopefully you didn't just snag that from my answer ;)

Comment: I didn't even read your answer until after that last change was finished.

Comment: lol either way I'm just joking. You get an upvote for all your edits.

Comment: I ran your code but the results are not what I expected. I get the interface name, but for the list<string>> items i get this `System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.String]`. Any idea why?@TonyVitabile

Comment: Because the default implementation of `ToString()` displays the type name, not the contents.  If you want to see the contents of the `List<string>` items, you're going to have to iterate over them.

Answer (score 2):

We need a bit more clarification as to how you expect to use this code but there are a couple options available to you. You can change the data structures that you're storing your values in to something that can be sorted "per network interface". For example:

```
private static Dictionary<string, List<string>> _interfaceIpAddresses
```

And then use the name of the network interface as the key to your dictionary as you loop over all the values.

```
if (unicast.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
{
     _interfaceIpAddresses[networkInterface.Name].Add(unicast.Address.ToString());
}
```

You could then change your getter to return the dictionary and you would have a sorted data structure containing all the IPAddresses etc indexed by their relative network interface.